# Barcode scanning to information

Tags: microsoft-excel, links, barcode

I have a bunch of 2d Barcode scanners that work with one of our programs.  The faculty just want to scan the patient id bar code and have the patient's information come up --- without opening the original program.  I was thinking I could do this in excel, but only the number comes up.  I need that specific number to show the information (name, patient id, birthday etc.)

Can excel do this or is there something else?

Comment: Barcode scanners are keyboards, as far as the computer is concerned: They just send a string of characters. You must program the application in order to automatically search or perform other actions based on this input. You could probably write a macro for Excel that filters based on input from a scanner.

Comment: You can do this two different ways in excel: 1) have all of the patient data in excel already, with the ID as a keyID and a bunch of vlookups ready. 2) Have a macro run on scan that opens the program, pulls the information, and closes again

Comment: Thank you Selkie --- we just need to be able to verify the name with the arm band so I think your first solution would work.  Unfortunately I don't know how to set up the vlookups.  Is there a simple explanation somewhere?

Comment: Kitet makes a very good point below. Excel is NOT the place for this information to be, unless Excel is just the front-end to a secured database with the patient information. If you're dealing with human patient information you really should be directing this request through qualified internal or contracted technical staff. In all likelihood, your existing records application should be capable of accepting input from a barcode scanner because, as was mentioned earlier, the scanner is basically just a keyboard to the computer.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working as an IT chief in healthcare for 15 yrs and no systems I know print personal data into the barcode, as it could be read by anyone (meaning other patients, visitors and such) who captures the code by using e.g. smartphone. This is unacceptable from the privacy point of view.

Because of this, barcode contains only the patient identifier (or specific hospitalisation episode, depends on healthcare application). This can be used in conjunction with an app to pull appropriate data from database, that is storing patient's personal and medical information.

In the light of this, you would have to write some application or a script that connects to the db and pulls required data. This is possible if all of the below is true:

- you have user name and password to access said database
- database allows logins from external hosts than the one it's hosted on, (e.g. three-tiered application could not allow connections) AND application vendor doesn't void your warranty if it notices your logins from app that isn't their own (some do that).
- if we're talking about doing it in excel, an ODBC connector/client must exist for this database and you have all the data that is required to construct a connection string / data source.
- you know how to construct SQL statement and have information on appropriate database tables that contain required data, OR you have access to database procedure that retrieves required data
- finally, you know some visual basic and can write a macro that gets cell value upon change (the barcode being read), connects to DSN, queries the DB, places required values in adjacent excel cell.

**ALTERNATIVE**

Your healthcare employer may have a contract with the application vendor and they can be asked to write all this for you, though charges may and will apply.

**REMARKS**

I'd personally do it on a LAN-only accessible webpage and write script in PHP. Of course I would **not** bypass a requirement of providing user name and password for any that require access to it, e.g. by hardcoding user / password into PHP script as this would compromise privacy security.

Comment: You bring up good points. There should be no place where someone can simply scan a bar code and retrieve patient information without there being authentication and security of some sort.